# Перестали сохраняться сессии при смене домена

Tags: сессия, домен

столкнулся с удивительной проблемой, не могу разгадать ее суть.
На всех страницах в самом начале использую:

```
ini_set('session.save_path', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/sessions');
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 259200);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 259200);

session_start();
```

Все было замечательно и работало корректно, сессии сохранялись в указанную папку. Затем я купил новый домен и подключил его к данному сайту, старый домен отвязал. В коде никакие изменения не вносил - сессии перестали сохраняться. Не могу понять, в чем дело, написал хостеру, они многие варианты предложили, но ничего не помогло.

Уже пробовал:

1. вместо `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` указывать точный путь - не помогло;
2. создавать новую папку для сессий с другим именем - не помогло;
3. удалять и создавать заново папку с текущим именем - не помогло;
4. прописывать `ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);` - не помогло;
5. отключать редирект на https - не помогло;
6. использовать `session_write_close();` - не помогло;
7. устанавливать права 777 - не помогло.

Уже проверил:

1. через `phpinfo()` проверил `session.save_path` - указан корректно;
2. права на папку 700, ограничений по записи нет;
3. в коде сессия нигде не разрушается (тем более код не менял, на другом домене работало);
4. `session_start();` везде есть;
5. место на диске есть;

Вообще сомневаюсь, что дело в коде, так как ранее на другом домене все работало. Единственная разница - новый домен с SSL сертификатом, а старый был без него. Может в этом есть какой-то подвох?